# Probability estimation by mean

Tags: probability

Does anybody know why we are able to estimate the probability by mean?  where

$$ \varepsilon \stackrel {\text{iid}} {\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$

[Original Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ePg.png)

> For any $\delta > 0$, we have
> $$ \begin{align} \mathbb{P}\left(\max_{i\leq j \leq T} \frac {|\varepsilon_j|} {\sqrt{T}} \leq \delta\right) 
> &= \prod_{j=1}^T \mathbb{P}\left( \frac {|\varepsilon_j|} {\sqrt{T}} \leq \delta\right) \\
> &= \left\{1 - \mathbb{P}\left( \frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right) \right\}^T \\
> &\geq \left[1 - \frac {1} {\delta^2 T}\mathbb{E}\left\{\varepsilon_1^2 I\left( \frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right)\right\}\right]^T
> \end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of indicator function, for any event $A$, we have

$$ \mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{E}[I_A] $$

So we have

$$ \mathbb{P}\left( \frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right)
= \mathbb{E}\left\{I\left( \frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right) \right\}$$

Also note the following common trick:

$$ xI(x>1) = \begin{cases} x > 1 \geq I(x>1) & \text{when } x > 1 \\
0 = I(x > 1) & \text{when } x \leq 1 \end{cases} $$

which implies that for any $x$,
$$ xI(x>1) \geq I(x > 1)$$

Put $\displaystyle x = \frac {\varepsilon_1^2} {\delta^2 T}$ we have

$$ \frac {\varepsilon_1^2} {\delta^2 T} I \left(\frac {\varepsilon_1^2} {\delta^2 T} > 1\right) \geq I \left(\frac {\varepsilon_1^2} {\delta^2 T} > 1\right) = I\left( \frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right) $$

surely. Taking expectation on both sides, we have

$$ \mathbb{E}\left\{I\left( \frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right) \right\} 
\leq \mathbb{E}\left\{ \frac {\varepsilon_1^2} {\delta^2 T} I \left(\frac {\varepsilon_1^2} {\delta^2 T} > 1\right) \right\}
= \frac {1} {\delta^2 T}\mathbb{E}\left\{\varepsilon_1^2 I\left(\frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right) \right\}$$

and rearranging and combining the result
$$ 1 - \mathbb{P}\left( \frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right)
\geq 1 - \frac {1} {\delta^2 T}\mathbb{E}\left\{\varepsilon_1^2 I\left(\frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right) \right\} $$

At last, since $f(x) = x^T$ is an increasing function for $x > 0$ (as $T$ is a positive integer), and not sure if the question is considering $T$ is sufficiently large in which the right hand side is also positive, so in such case we also have
$$ \left\{1 - \mathbb{P}\left( \frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right)\right\}^T
\geq \left[ 1 - \frac {1} {\delta^2 T}\mathbb{E}\left\{\varepsilon_1^2 I\left(\frac {|\varepsilon_1|} {\sqrt{T}} > \delta\right) \right\} \right]^T $$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I didn't write it. We have to prove that the max(.) is converge to 0 with probability. So we have T to infinite.